# From FLA to MCA - NEC

Tags: power, circuits

I have a piece of equipment with an FLA (Full Load Amps) of X amperes, and it is a small circuit appliance. Is there a rule in NEC to calculate the MCA (Minimum Circuit Ampacity) based on the FLA.

MCA = 125% X FLA

It's correct?